# React 16.4 Conditional Render Based on Promise

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to conditionally render a block of code. The condition `canProject` can be either true or false. This is evaluated with the `checkRole()` function.

The problem is the `checkRole()` returns a promise. By the time the promise is returned the content is already rendered.

How can I use `checkRole()` to conditionally render a code block? Note, I use the `canProject` condition in a lot of places in the html code, so I would like to use it in the `return (` as needed by adding `{canProject &&`

```
render() {

  const canProject = checkRole('project'); //this returns a promise

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="row">
        {canProject &&
          <div className="col-lg-4">
          </div>
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: what content is returned already?

Comment: @JonathanAkweteyOkine in the `return(` I have the whole page setup with bootstrap. Some small snippets of that code need to be rendered conditionally. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 4):

Keep track of the promise's status in state:

```
this.state = {
  promiseFulfilled: false
}

const canProject = checkRole('project').then(() => this.setState({promiseFulfilled: true}))

render() {

  const { promiseFulfilled } = this.state

  if (promiseFulfilled) {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="row">
          {canProject &&
            <div className="col-lg-4">
            </div>
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  } else {
    return null
  } 
}
```

For posterity: this is the proper way to do so with more recent versions of React (version >16.8) using [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html):

```
const [ promiseFulfilled, setPromiseFulfilled ] = useState(false)

const canProject = checkRole('project').then(() => setPromiseFulfilled(true))

render() {

  if (promiseFulfilled) {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="row">
          {canProject &&
            <div className="col-lg-4">
            </div>
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  } else {
    return null
  } 
}
```

Comment: Hrm.. we're on React 16.4, this looks like it's only on >16.8

Comment: Hooks are just a nicer way to handle state. I've changed the answer to reflect the way of managing state in the earlier versions. I'd definitely suggest upgrading the React version when you get a chance, though.

Comment: this works. Answer missing one closing `)` at the end of `.then()`  Is there not a way to do it without waiting for the promise to evaluate. Like an on the fly state change, then it would render?

Comment: Yep, that was a typo! Thanks for catching it. I've updated the answer to fix it.

Comment: If this answer works for you, please accept it when you get a chance.

Comment: double checking it now

Comment: that didn't work, unfortunately. It loops the `checkRole` endlessly if I use the `.then` portion

Comment: I tried moving `canProject` out of the render function. See if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the most elegant way to achieve this:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {canProjectR: false}; //set to false initally
}

//set the canProjectR to the response which is true or false
componentDidMount() {
  this.checkRole('project').then(res => { this.setState({ canProjectR: res}) });
}

//use this.state.canProject && as needed
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="row">
        {this.state.canProject && 
          <div className="col-lg-4">
          </div>
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You really should just upgrade React and use hooks. `componentDidMount` may become deprecated one day (`componentWillMount` already is). In addition, while `componentDidMount` blocks the browser screen from updating, hooks do not. Not to mention that they're easier and less lines of code when you get used to them.

Comment: @223seneca this avoids the extra `if (promiseFulfilled) {} else` statement in render so it is less lines of code. That `if (promiseFulfilled)`  blocks the render until the promise is fulfilled as well.  `componentDidMount` is standard in React development, they are more likely to do a breaking change to hooks than that. I upvoted your answer, I just think this one is simpler.